# How aut create raw number in column B if relevant cell in column C is empty via VBA?

Tags: vba, excel, function, excel-formula

How Can I create code in VBA, which can do below command: 
- Once any info (value or data) entered to the relative cell in column C, automatically create number for that raw in column B.
For example: once user entered request text in column C4,AUT create request number in column B4. I have created below code, however it is not working. Could you please help what is wrong?

```
Sub requestnumber()

Dim lRow As Integer
Dim i As Integer
Dim m As Integer

lRow = Cells(Rows.Count, 2).End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To i = lRow

m = Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Activate

If Range("B1").Offset(i, 0) <> "" Then

Range("A1").Offset(i, 0) = lRow

Exit For

End If

Next i

End Sub
```

Thanks!
Shahla H.

Comment: Must the numbers be unique and not repeated? Are there limitations on the numbers assigned?

Comment: You can't declare multiple Dim  on same line. You should be using For i = 1 To lRow and i think  Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Activate not m =  Range("B1").Offset(i, 0).Activate

Comment: `it is not working` does not describe the problem that is being experienced. it gives absolutely no information that can be used to provide a solution

Comment: And do you really mean to loop column B seeing if  cell in same column are not empty and if is not empty then set column A value in current row to lrow value? Your question would imply not. As a start you would need to change your offset logic.

Answer (score 1):

I am trying to guess what are you asking for. If you need number of row in column B when cell in column C is filled you don't need VBA. Just type formula in B column:

```
=IF(ISBLANK(C1), "", ROW())
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is assign a unique request id number in col B when people make an entry in Col C. In which case you need to only run your code after data entry, so you need to attach your code to the worksheet update event in the code module for the sheet:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
 If Target.Column = 3 Then
      Target.Offset(0, -1).Value = Application.WorksheetFunction.Max(Range("b:b")) + 1

 End If
End Sub
```